# Build a required group in argparse.ArgumentParser

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, arguments, argparse

I was wondering about have a `RequiredGroup` class to ensure, during [`ArgumentParse.parse_known_args`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py#L1825), that *at least* one of its actions were supplied. I mean, opposing `_MutuallyExclusiveGroup` that allow **at most one** action when `required=True` argument is provided, the objective here is one **at-least-one** group

My idea was to extend `ArgumentParser` class to process it similarly as it's done with `_MutuallyExclusiveGroup`. However it's done using some variables constructed inside the method that aren't available after it.

Here is the method's snippet that process exclusive mutuality of referent group's actions:

```
# make sure all required groups had one option present
        for group in self._mutually_exclusive_groups:
            if group.required:
                for action in group._group_actions:
                    if action in seen_non_default_actions:
                        break

                # if no actions were used, report the error
                else:
                    names = [_get_action_name(action)
                             for action in group._group_actions
                             if action.help is not SUPPRESS]
                    msg = _('one of the arguments %s is required')
                    self.error(msg % ' '.join(names))
```

As `seen_non_default_actions` attribute is not available in class, I couldn't figure out how to do this goal.

Some clue about how to work around it?

Comment: In one of the Python bug/issues I explored extending the mutually_exclusive_group concept to handle all kinds of logic (and nesting).  As you note, we need access to a variable that's local to `_parse_known_args`.  So the test has to be added to that method.  Or that method needs some refactoring.  If needed I could point you to the relevant bug/issue.

Comment: But - a simpler alternative is to test the arguments after parsing.  If you use the default default `None`, `is not None` is a reliable test for occurrence.  Or with meaningful defaults you won't care whether the arguments are provided or not.  (How will you indicate this requirement in the `usage`?)

Comment: Please, I would like to see the raised issue and your approach solution

Comment: `_MutuallyExclusiveGroup` restrict just one option to be supplied, ensuring one with `require=true`. I want to have a group that allows multiple options to be supplied, however ensure **at least** one of them have appeared. I will increase description to be more clear!

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue11588

Comment: Pretty elegant and flexible solution, hpaulj! I get into the repository contains the proposed modifications, I'll try to figure out mine from it. Would you like to register this alternative through an answer? It could also help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution based in the suggested [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj?tab=profile)'s [argparse usage_tests improvement](https://github.com/hpaulj/argparse_issues/blob/d24834b07da3bf116dd52ccabd77d10c5f678095/argparse.py#L3140).

Similarly to the inspirational algorithm, it consists in taking advantage of `_ActionsContainer._registries` to store some `'usage_tests'` that run after all `ArgumentParser.parse_known_args` process. But distinctly, I didn't rewrite the original method, instead I just made my own `ArgumentParser` subclass to wrap the function, checking and running the registered `usage_tests`

```
class MyArgumentParser(ArgumentParser):
    def parse_known_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
        namespace, argv  = super(MyArgumentParser, self).parse_known_args(args, namespace)

        for test in self._registries.get('usage_tests', {}).values():
            test(self, args or sys.argv[1:], namespace)

        return namespace, argv

    def add_required_group(self, *args, **kwargs):
        group = _RequiredGroup(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._action_groups.append(group)
        return group
```

As, this way, I still have no access of `seen_non_default_actions` variable, I'm working around it by catch arguments through `sys.argv[1:]`

```
class _RequiredGroup(_ArgumentGroup):
    def __init__(self, container, **kwargs):
        super(_RequiredGroup, self).__init__(container, **kwargs)

        name = str(id(self)) # a unique key for this test
        self.register('usage_tests', name, self.test)

    @property
    def _option_strings(self):
        option_strings = []
        for action in self._group_actions:
            option_strings += action.option_strings
        return option_strings

    def test(self, parser, args, namespace):
        for option in self._option_strings:
            if option in args:
                break

        else:  # if no actions were used, report the error
            if self._option_strings:
                parser.error(f"one of the arguments {' '.join(self._option_strings)} is required")
```